# viewDidLoad getting called every time after calling popViewControllerAnimated:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, viewdidload

I have a vc called `ViewControllerOne`, when the user taps a `UITableViewCell` I call a `push segue` and navigate to `ViewControllerTwo`. In `ViewControllerTwo` I'm hiding the navigation bar, therefore I've created a custom back button:

```
- (IBAction)backBttn:(id)sender {

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

that works perfectly, but the `viewDidLoad` getting called (in `ViewControllerTwo`) every time I navigate back to `ViewControllerOne` and than open `ViewControllerTwo` again. Am I right that `viewDidLoad` getting called because I'm using `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]`? Or it must have another reason?

Comment: In which UIViewController subclass is `viewDidLoad` getting called multiple times?

Comment: @ndmeiri in `ViewControllerTwo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right you are seeing viewDidLoad called on the view controller you are pushing to. (`ViewControllerTwo`). If you push from `ViewControllerOne` to `ViewControllerTwo`, `ViewControllerTwo`'s viewDidLoad is being called.

If you then click the back button to pop `ViewControllerTwo`, return to `ViewControllerOne`, then push to `ViewControllerTwo` again, you see `viewDidLoad` being called a second time.

This is expected behavior.  Push segues (and all other segues except unwind segues) create a new instance of the view controller they are presenting.

Likewise, popping/dismissing deallocates the view controller you are leaving.

Comment: Thanks Duncan, it's good to know that is a normal behavior. Do you think is it a bad routine and I need to find another solution? Or it's ok? Actually everything works fine, but I need to fetch some data from a server every time I open `ViewControllerTwo` and I'm a little bit confused where should I do this because usually I'm doing it in the `viewWillAppear`, but in this case it seems `viewDidLoad` is fine too.

Comment: Generally you should avoid doing network transactions every time you load a view controller. Instead have a network manager singleton that does the work for you, and remembers how recently it fetched the data. When you return to your view controller, ask the network manager if you have current data. If so, use it. If not, request an update from the network manager.

Answer (score 1):

When you pop the view controller from the navigation stack, the view that it manages is deallocated (or unloaded). Therefore, when you open `ViewControllerTwo` again, the view must be loaded again. This is why `viewDidLoad` is called multiple times in your case.